# Can someone please explain this jquery datepicker example

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Here is a link to the site:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html

I'm looking at the text box called date 1.

There is a little calendar icon next to the text box.  When it's clicked, the datepicker opens.  What makes this work?  I can't seem to figure it out.

I understand how the text box works because it has a class called .date-pick which gets the datepicker function with the jquery.

But the calendar is applied with a class called dp-choose-date.  No where in the source can I find this class.

I think I'm confused a little here.

Comment: Please post the relevant code within your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The class is being applied by the date picker plug-in, probably using the `addClass` function.  The plug-in, when it's initialized, probably creates a `DIV` (`id=;dp-popup'`) that has the necessary values for the current month.  That `DIV` is hidden (`display:none`) but still has the class of dp-popup when first initialized.  When you click in the textbox or click the button, there's an event handler assigned to those events (`focus` for the textbox, `click` for the button) that sets the display style of the `DIV` to not be hidden and it also positions it right below the text box.

I didn't dig into the code a whole lot, but looking at the markup a little, that's how I suspect it's working.

Comment: @Carl - you didn't anything to your comment.